# Failed to execute goal in maven-archetype-plugin, Archetype IT 'testInstall' failed, Cannot run additions goals

Tags: java, maven

I am attempting to use `mvn clean install` to build a project, and I am running into the following issue.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project module-archetype:
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'testInstall' failed: Cannot run additions goals.
```

I have already attempted to use the workarounds suggested in similar topics here, and here, and also here. Specifically, I...

- Copied `mvn.cmd` and renamed the copy `mvn.bat` in the Maven home directory
- Added dependency information about `maven-invoker` to `pom.xml`, as well as numerous variations of that based on other research.
- Changing the version from 2.3 to 3.0.1 and others

None of them have worked. The only difference being I get this error instead:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project module-archetype:
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'testInstall' failed: Execution failure: exit code = 1
```

All other google/stackoverflow searches have yielded nothing. For the record, I am on a Windows 10 machine. I have the Java 11 JDK and Maven 3.6.0.

The relevant portion of the relevant `pom.xml` file:

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
        <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

And the full log of the original error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project module-archetype:
[ERROR] Archetype IT 'testInstall' failed: Cannot run additions goals.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:integration-test (default-integration-test) on project module-archetype:
Archetype IT 'testInstall' failed: Cannot run additions goals.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
Archetype IT 'testInstall' failed: Cannot run additions goals.
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.IntegrationTestMojo.execute (IntegrationTestMojo.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

[UPDATE] Apparently these archetypes were (according to the original dev) used to help build other modules, and can be ignored now, so that's what I'm moving ahead with. Frustrating that I was never able to solve the problem, but at least I can move forward.

Comment: What kind of project are you trying to build?

Comment: @JFMeier I do apologize, but I'm afraid I am very new to both the project and Maven in general. It's a web application with a Java backend for doing data processing, if that's what you meant? Could you elaborate?

Comment: You obviously are trying to do something with archetypes, and I do not understand what.

Comment: The only information I was able to get from the original designer is that they were used to help build new modules, and can now be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, seems to be a Maven-Bug on Windows, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-488

Workaround from the discussion (https://github.com/oasp/oasp4j/issues/238#issuecomment-304780640):

```
cd %MAVEN_HOME%\bin
mklink mvn.bat mvn.cmd
```